# Select2 dropdown on Modal working weirdly

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am working with a `Select2` dropdown in a Modal.

Earlier I wasn't able to search in the input dropdown, hence I added following lines

```
dropdownParent: $("#modalId")
```

After adding the above line while initializing `Select2`, search is up but now the positioning of dropdown do not work as expected.

Since on my page there is a list of items, and for each item I have attached a common Modal to popup. For the first 2 items the `Select2` dropdown in the modal works fine, but as soon as I scroll down to other items and open up the modal, the dropdown shifts down.

Couldn't figure it out.

`Select2` initialization code

```
 jQuery(".select3").select2({
        width: '100%',
        dropdownParent: $("#modal-id")
    });
```

Modal Code

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" id="modal-id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @Html.DropDownList("DropDown", new SelectList(ViewBag.Users, "Value", "Text", new { @id = "dropdown" }), "Please select", new { @class = "form-control select3 " })
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer" style="border-top:0px;">

                    <input type="hidden" id="id">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light delete-confirm" disabled>Confirm</button>


                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
```

Comment: Share your rest of code

Comment: @PankajMakwana done